# How to Implement Structured Data in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions, backend

I am doing an SEO consultancy on a Magento eCommerce store and I'd like to suggest the use of structured data, such as:

- Breadcrumbs
- Products
- Price
- Availability
- Reviews
- Ratings

My question: If there is an easy way to implement this on an existing ecommerce website, such as a popular extension, or via the backend of the Magento CMS. I'm a noob with Magento so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to modify some template in order to achieve this.
For example you can modify the way the breadcrumbs are rendered by changing the contents of `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml`
For products you have:
`app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` and all the files in `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view/` folder.
For price is a little trickier. See what you can change in `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/price.phtml`
The availability can be found in `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view/type/` and it depends on the product type.
Reviews and ratings are rendered by `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/review/product/list.phtml`.
I'm not that experienced with structured data so I cannot tell you what you need to change. But I think you can work your magic if you know where to do the changes.

Comment: Excellent, saved me some Googling.

Answer (score 7):

Structured data, also known as [Microdata](http://schema.org/), is descriptive metadata that is a function of your markup.

Because microdata is **so closely tied to your markup**, it is generally recommended that you update your theme **manually** to **include** microdata elements. There are some tutorials, and some "plugins" that will *supposedly* achieve this for you, but from experience (implementing on half a dozen sites) is that if you have any theme customizations at all you're really stuck with a manual effort.

An example of such customization would be as follows:

The Schema.org Doc: http://schema.org/Product

> Open your template/catalog/product/view.phtml
>
> div class=”product-essential”: Insert the itemtype

**Source:** https://www.revitalagency.com/blog/add-product-schema-microdata-to-magento/

---

Some further reading:

http://schema.org/docs/gs.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_(HTML)

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176035

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the do it yourself tip, will do it like that.